# Using XML::LibXML to find and replace specific portions of a CableLabs 1.0 XML file

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, xml-libxml

I have tried `XML Simple`, but due to the fact that it just reads the XML into a hash, the output is useless when run against the DTD. Learned it the hard way.

So I have adopted `XML::LibXML`, the funny thing is the requirements that I found most difficult to accomplish with `XML::Simple`, were the easiest. However I am finding that some of easier things to do in `XML::Simple` are proving to be impossible (with my lack of understanding of DOM, and some confusing behaviors with `XML::LibXML`).

So here is a sample of the XML:

```
    <Metadata>
        <ADI Name="movie" />
        <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about" value="who cares" />
        <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about as well" value="who cares" />
        <App_Data Name="ChangeMe" Value="" />
    </Metadata>
    <Metadata>
        <ADI Name="photo" />
        <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about" value="who cares" />
        <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about as well" value="who cares" />
        <App_Data Name="ChangeMe" Value="" />
    </Metadata>
    <Metadata>
        <ADI Name="poster" />
        <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about" value="who cares" />
        <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about as well" value="who cares" />
        <App_Data Name="ChangeMe" Value="" />
    </Metadata>
```

Note: I have simplified this for the use in this post.

So basically I have to use the `Name` field in the `<ADI>` tag to confirm that I am in the correct area of the DOM to make the change to the `Value` attribute in the `<App_Data>` tag that who's `Name` is `ChangeMe`.

This is the snippet of code that I have come up with... and failed miserably.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml2 = XML::LibXML->new();
my $data = $xml2->parse_file("adi.xml");
my $movie;
my $photo;
my $poster;

foreach my $test ($data->findnodes('//Metadata')) {
    if ($test->findvalues('./ADI/@Name[.="movie"]')){
        $movie = 1;
        undef $photo;
        undef $poster;
    }
    elsif ($test->findvalues('./ADI/@Name[.="photo"]')){
        undef $movie;
        $photo = 1;
        undef $poster;
    }
    elsif ($test->findvalues('./ADI/@Name[.="poster"]')){
        undef $movie;
        undef $photo;
        $poster = 1;
    }
}
```

I don't have anything beyond this, because it doesn't work. I get an error something along the lines of

```
Can't locate object method "findvalues" via package "XML::LibXML::Element"
```

As a bonus to this question, what if I wanted to completely remove the `<Metadata>` (and all children) for the ones that contained photo and/or poster?

Comment: `undef $var;` is a special version of `$var = undef;` that causes Perl to do extra work. Use the latter.

Comment: It's unclear what you intend to do with `<App_Data Name="ChangeMe"... />` once you identify the `Metadata` type. What will it look like after the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try for starters.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml2 = XML::LibXML->new();
my $data = $xml2->parse_file("adi.xml");

foreach my $test ($data->findnodes('//Metadata')) {
    if ($test->findnodes('./ADI/@Name[.="movie"]')){
        print "movie\n";
    }
    elsif ($test->findnodes('./ADI/@Name[.="photo"]')){
        print "photo\n";
    }
    elsif ($test->findnodes('./ADI/@Name[.="poster"]')){
        print "poster\n";
    }
}
```

There is no `findvalues` method.  What you want to do is use `findnodes`, which will return to you a list of nodes matching the XPath expression.  Once you have that, you can iterate over the list and extract any of the data you need, much like you're already doing for `Metadata`.

Also, I'm assuming your XML file has a single root-level element.  I used the modified version below to test the above code.

```
<root>
   <Metadata>
        <ADI Name="movie" />
        <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about" value="who cares" />
        <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about as well" value="who cares" />
        <App_Data Name="ChangeMe" Value="" />
    </Metadata>
    <Metadata>
        <ADI Name="photo" />
        <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about" value="who cares" />
        <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about as well" value="who cares" />
        <App_Data Name="ChangeMe" Value="" />
    </Metadata>
    <Metadata>
        <ADI Name="poster" />
        <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about" value="who cares" />
        <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about as well" value="who cares" />
        <App_Data Name="ChangeMe" Value="" />
    </Metadata>
</root>
```

I find [this cheatsheet](http://refcards.com/docs/forda/perl-xml-libxml/perl-xml-libxml-refcard-a4.pdf) useful for Perl's LibXML library.

Answer (score 2):

- Where did you find `findvalues`? Docs:

  ```
  @nodes = $node->findnodes( $xpath_expression );
  $result = $node->find( $xpath );
  print $node->findvalue( $xpath );
  ```
- Why so many uses of `.`?

  ```
  ./ADI/@Name[.="movie"]
  ```

  should probably be

  ```
  ADI[@Name="movie"]
  ```
- You have more than one Metadata element, but you set the variables based on the last one alone.
- You shouldn't be using three different variables to store one piece of information.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file("adi.xml");

for my $metadata ($doc->findnodes('//Metadata')) {
    my ($adi_type) = $metadata->find('ADI/@Name')
       or next;

    my ($app_data) = $metadata->find('App_Data[@Name="ChangeMe"]');

    if ($adi_type eq 'movie') {
       ...
    }
    elsif ($adi_type eq 'photo') {
       ...
    }
    elsif ($adi_type eq 'poster') {
       ...
    }
}
```

---

Or you could even use:

```
my ($movie_adi) = $doc->findnodes('//Metadata[ADI/@Name="movie"]');
my ($movie_app_data) = $movie_adi->findnodes('App_Data[@Name="ChangeMe"]');
...

my ($photo_adi) = $doc->findnodes('//Metadata[ADI/@Name="photo"]');
my ($photo_app_data) = $photo_adi->findnodes('App_Data[@Name="ChangeMe"]');
...

my ($poster_adi) = $doc->findnodes('//Metadata[ADI/@Name="poster"]');
my ($poster_app_data) = $poster_adi->findnodes('App_Data[@Name="ChangeMe"]');
...
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot can be done in the XPath expression to find the nodes you're interested in.

This program will do what you ask. I have added a root element `<root>` to your data to make it into a well-formed XML document.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'adi.xml', no_blanks => 1);

for my $metadata ($doc->findnodes('//Metadata')) {
  if ( $metadata->findnodes('ADI[@Name = "movie" or @Name = "photo"]') ) {
    $metadata->parentNode->removeChild($metadata);
  }
}

print $doc->toString(1);
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <Metadata>
    <ADI Name="poster"/>
    <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about" value="who cares"/>
    <App_Data Name="Something I don't care about as well" value="who cares"/>
    <App_Data Name="ChangeMe" Value=""/>
  </Metadata>
</root>
```

Comment: Nice one. Mayhap `$metadata->unbindNode();` is a more concise way of detaching the node?